color half of the borders with GeoPandas
I have three polygons with common borders.
I can't figure out how to color only the inner half of the border.
For the moment I have:
data = [
        (gpd.read_file("shape1.shp"), "#f2a6a5"),
        (gpd.read_file("shape2.shp"), "#fbebc0"),
        (gpd.read_file("shape3.shp"), "#dacbab"),
    ]
    for poly, color in data:
        poly.boundary.plot(
            ax=ax,
            color=color,
            linestyle="solid",
            linewidth=6,
        )


So, I would like to color only the inner part of the border. This would allow for a two-color border between two polygons.

IIUC, you can apply a negative buffer before the plot :
D = -0.06 # to adjust

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for poly, color in data:
    poly.buffer(D).boundary.plot( # <<< here
        ax=ax,
        color=color,
        linestyle="solid",
        linewidth=6,
    )



thank you, it's almost perfect. On the other hand I have points which appear in the middle of a certain polygon. Do you have any idea why? this only happens with a negative buffer.

You're welcome and regarding your question, you're the only one who can find the answer (since you have the shapefiles). You can yet try using make_valid and see if it solves your problem: poly.make_valid().buffer(D).... If not, if you manage to make a minimal reproducible example and open a new question, I'll be happy to help ;).

This answer from @Kadir Şahbaz might also help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/409398/197233
